# Why is the heatmap displayed with only one color?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to get a normal heatmap as output, but the heatmap I am getting is a single color heatmap.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(corr_df, annot=True, fmt=".1g", vmin=1, vmax=1, center=0,linewidths=0.5, linecolor='Black')
heatmap.set_title("Correlation HeatMap Between Variable")
heatmap.set_xticklabels(heatmap.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[Getting this heatmap as output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZVTb.png)

Comment: This is because of `vmin=1, vmax=1`. Maybe you meant to write `vmin=-1, vmax=1`?  Note that `vmin` is the value that should correspond to the lowest color value, and `vmax` to the highest.  Setting `vmin` and `vmax` to the same value inevitably creates a weird outcome.

Comment: Note that to rotate the tick labels, nowadays `heatmap.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)` is the more recommended approach.